# How do I evaluate a Symbolic variable in SymbolicC++?

Tags: c++, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation, symbolicc++

I have been trying out a couple computer algebra libraries for C++ to use with a vector calculus course I am taking. I am having trouble with nonlinear equations in GiNaC and in [SymbolicC++](http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html) it actually worked.

Here is a simple example, but the problem is I can't figure out how to evaluate to a number and maybe cast it to a double or float:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "symbolicc++.h"

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    Symbolic x("x"), y("y");

    Equation e1 = (x^2) + (y^2) == 13;
    Equation e2 = (x^2) - y == 7;

    Equations eqs = {e1, e2};
    list<Symbolic> symbs = {x, y};
    list<Equations> sols = solve(eqs, symbs);

    Symbolic x_sol, y_sol;
    int i = 1;
    for( auto iter1 = sols.begin(); iter1 != sols.end(); iter1++)
    {
        x_sol = x.subst((*(*iter1).begin()));
        y_sol = y.subst((*(--(*iter1).end())));
        cout << "p" << i << " = {" << x_sol << ", " << y_sol << "};" << endl;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With that output I can copy and past it to `ginsh` and it evaluates just fine, but it stays in expanded form in SymbolicC++.

The exact ouput I am getting is as follows:

```
p1 = {1/2*(-2*(25)^(1/2)+26)^(1/2), -1/2*(25)^(1/2)-1/2};
p2 = {1/2*(2*(25)^(1/2)+26)^(1/2), 1/2*(25)^(1/2)-1/2};
p3 = {-1/2*(-2*(25)^(1/2)+26)^(1/2), -1/2*(25)^(1/2)-1/2};
p4 = {-1/2*(2*(25)^(1/2)+26)^(1/2), 1/2*(25)^(1/2)-1/2};
```

How can I evaluate expressions like these and cast them to `double`s?

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this an answer to almost a year old question.  But there's no way to directly cast a string to a number.  You would need to calculate the floating-point value you're interested - the same way you do it on a calculator. https://code.google.com/p/exprtk/ is a link to a very easy to use library to accomplish exactly what you're looking for. You will have to get the Symbolic object into a string class using a string stream

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cout << "p" << i << " = {" << double(x_sol) << ", " << double(y_sol) << "};" << endl;
```

Comment: It compiled but at runtime:"`Attempted to cast -1/2*(25)^(1/2)-1/2 to double failed.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SymbolicError'
Aborted`"